# Routes with multiple parameters not working properly in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to make my urls seo friendly. I want my urls to be like http://www.example.com/products/asus-zenfone-4-5649. I am using the following code. But it is not working properly.

In my routes.php,

```
Route::get('/products/{name}-{id}', 'ProductController@showProduct');
```

And in my controller,

```
public function showProduct($name, $id)
{
    echo $name;
    echo $id;
}
```

If the url is like http://www.example.com/products/motoe-5649, it displays

```
$name = motoe
$id = 5649              ---> Working fine
```

If the url is like http://www.example.com/products/asus-zenfone-4-5649, it displays

```
$name = asus
$id = zenfone-4-5649    ---> Not working properly
```

**Note: Do not want to use like.**

```
Route::get('/products/{name}/{id}', 'ProductController@showProduct');
```

How can I solve the same?

Answer (score 0):

This `Route::get('/products/{name}-{id}', 'ProductController@showProduct');` expects exactly two parameters. One named `name` after the `/products/` and before `-` and one named `id` right after the `-`. So whatever exists after `-` is considered to be the `id` parameter no matter how many `-` it contains.

If you want to use more parameters then add them to your route and controller's method declaration. If you have optional parameters use the question mark next to them to make them optional in your route and assign default value to null in your method.

Route:

```
Route::get('products/{name}-{id}-{parameter1?}-{parameter2?}, ['as' => 'products', 'uses' => 'ProductController@showProduct']);
```

Controller's method:

```
public function showProduct($name, $id, $parameter1 = null, $parameter2 = null)
{
    return $name.$id.$parameter1.$parameter2;
}
```

call route:

```
{{route('products', ['aName', 'anId'])}}
```

or

```
{{route('products', ['anotherName', 'anotherId', 'aParameter1', 'aParameter2'])}}
```

shall both work. Of course each will give a different url.

Comment: My question is different.